# DHCP_HOSTNAME isn't working consistently in RedHat 7

Tags: redhat, dhcp, networkmanager

Under RedHat/Centos 6.x I used DHCP_HOSTNAME=`hostname -s` in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 to pass client hostname to DHCP for registration in DNS and this worked flawlessly.  I'm now working with RedHat 7 and it appears to work inconsistently, if at all.

I have a particular VM (which was cloned, in case this is relevant) which will not register its hostname with DHCP and thus through to DNS.  I've tried DHCP_HOSTNAME=`hostname`, DHCP_HOSTNAME=$(hostname) and other variants, but I've also tried DHCP_HOSTNAME=(actual hostname) to no avail.  Disabling NetworkManager seemed to have no effect.   DHCP/DNS servers are in Windows/AD, and DHCP is configured to update hostnames in DNS.  Other Linux variants (Ubuntu/Debian derivatives, Redhat/Centos 6.x) do not exhibit this problem.

Has anyone else encountered this?  Would appreciate any insight you could provide.

---

Updating with some more information.  It turns out that DHCP option 12 is being sent, but it is also being requested by dhclient.  I wonder if this is causing some confusion with the DHCP server.  Is this expected behavior?

tcpdump/dhcpdump output:

```
[root@myhostname ~]# tcpdump -lenx -i 3 -s 1500 port bootps or port bootpc | dhcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens192, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 1500 bytes
TCPdump 3.8.x output
  TIME: 09:36:15.438666
    IP: > (00:50:56:92:7c:55) >  (Broadcast)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: 932b3b7f
  SECS: 0
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 00:50:56:92:7c:55:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         3 (DHCPREQUEST)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        192.168.50.79
OPTION:  12 ( 19) Host name                 myhostname
OPTION:  55 ( 18) Parameter Request List      1 (Subnet mask)
                                             28 (Broadcast address)
                                              2 (Time offset)
                                            121 (Classless Static Route)
                                             15 (Domainname)
                                              6 (DNS server)
                                             12 (Host name)
                                             40 (NIS domain)
                                             41 (NIS servers)
                                             42 (NTP servers)
                                             26 (Interface MTU)
                                            119 (Domain Search)
                                              3 (Routers)
                                            121 (Classless Static Route)
                                            249 (MSFT - Classless route)
                                             33 (Static route)
                                            252 (MSFT - WinSock Proxy Auto Detect)
                                             42 (NTP servers)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TIME: 09:36:15.441067
    IP: > (00:50:56:92:44:c4) >  (Broadcast)
    OP: 2 (BOOTPREPLY)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: 932b3b7f
  SECS: 0
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 192.168.50.79
SIADDR: 192.168.50.28
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 00:50:56:92:7c:55:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: pxelinux.0.
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         5 (DHCPACK)
OPTION:  58 (  4) T1                        3600 (60m)
OPTION:  59 (  4) T2                        6300 (1h45m)
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      7200 (2h)
OPTION:  54 (  4) Server identifier         192.168.50.4
OPTION:   1 (  4) Subnet mask               255.255.255.0
OPTION:  15 ( 10) Domainname                domain.local
OPTION:   6 ( 12) DNS server                192.168.1.4
OPTION:   3 (  4) Routers                   192.168.50.1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Interesting, I can't get NetworkMangler to send a hostname at all. I suggest you get hold of your Red Hat rep.